# MVVM - Creating observable collections from BackgroundWorker - DependencySource / Object error

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, backgroundworker, dependency-properties

I've just introduced a loading animation to my application. The code runs, but when I come to interface with the application, it crashes with the error "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."

I've modified the code so that only calls that retrieve & process data should be on the background thread, and any sort of ObservableCollections are initialised after on the UI thread.

However, the error is still being thrown! If I just have the background worker process the 'RetrieveItems' method, then it behaves, but the majority of processing is done in the 'ApplyFilters' method - which is quite extensive, but ultimate returns a list of IItemGroupViewModel. What sort of things might be being done in here that are interfering with the UI? 
It's displaying the ItemGroups that is the problem, I believe - although the list of groups returns properly and is visible on the UI thread. I can also view the initial tab fine, which contains ItemViewModels that were created in the RetrieveItems method.

I'm finding this impossible to debug too.

Here is the code:

```
    public void Start()
    {
        var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;           
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;

        _tabList = GenerateTabs();

        DisplayLoadingScreen = true;           
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemVMs = RetrieveItems(_pciSelectionViewModel.SelectedPcis);

        var itemGroups = ApplyFilters(
             _pciSelectionViewModel.SelectedPcis, itemVMs, 
             _pciSelectionViewModel.UserQuestionList, _tabList);
        e.Result = Tuple.Create<IEnumerable<IItemViewModel>, IEnumerable<IItemGroupViewModel>>(itemVMs, itemGroups);
    }


    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayLoadingScreen = false;
        var res = e.Result as Tuple<IEnumerable<IItemViewModel>, IEnumerable<IItemGroupViewModel>>;
        InitialiseObservableCollections(res.Item1, res.Item2);
    }


    public void InitialiseObservableCollections(IEnumerable<IItemViewModel> itemVMs,
        IEnumerable<IItemGroupViewModel> itemGroups)
    {
        AddAllocatedTabsToItems(itemGroups);

        ItemGroupCollection = new ObservableCollection<IItemGroupViewModel>(itemGroups);
        PciCollection = new ObservableCollection<IPciViewModel>(_pciSelectionViewModel.SelectedPcis);
        TabList = new ObservableCollection<IAnalysisTabViewModel>(_tabList);
        ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<IItemViewModel>(itemVMs);
        AssignedTabFiltersCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(GenerateItemTypeFilters(_tabList));

        foreach (var itemGroup in itemGroups)
        {
            itemGroup.PopulateInternalData(_pciSelectionViewModel.SelectedPcis);
        }
        _tabList.ToList().ForEach(t => t.Update());

    }
```

Comment: If you had slow starting application and now trying to add splash screen, then more likely problem is what you forgot to redesign it. To example, when opening database, you should not immediately populate data (via bindings, etc). Instead, you have only open them and load data later. Or, if you consider pre-loading, there should be another data-layer (in model).

Comment: What is `_tabList` in your `bgw_DoWork()` method?